# (Java) Exception "GC overhead limit exceeded", how can I resolve this?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I got the following exception when trying to run the code in eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.addItemListener(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setModel(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ComputerBookingSystemGUI.<init>(ComputerBookingSystemGUI.java:23)
    at ComputerBookingSystemGUI.main(ComputerBookingSystemGUI.java:59)
```

Initially, I was just running out of memory, so I increased the dedicated memory to `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m`. This resolved this issue, but created this new one. When I try to execute the following program (a computer booking system with a gui):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import main.kof;

public class ComputerBookingSystemGUI extends JFrame {

    int computer = 30;

    private JLabel computerL;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JTextField tf;

    ComputerBookingSystemGUI() {
        while (1 == 1) {

            JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
            add(tf);

            JButton button = new JButton("Book");
            add(button);

            JButton button2 = new JButton("Cancel");
            add(button2);


            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String g = tf.getText();
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(g);
                    if (computer >= i) {
                        computer = computer - i;

                    } else {
                        JLabel label = new JLabel("There aren't enough computers");
                        add(label);
                    }

                }
            });
            button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {
                    String g = tf.getText();
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(g);
                    int q = computer + i;
                    if (q <= 30) {
                        computer = computer + i;
                    } else {
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("There aren't enough computers.");
                        add(label2);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComputerBookingSystemGUI gui = new ComputerBookingSystemGUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(250, 250);
        gui.setTitle("Computer booking system.");
    }
}
```

Any offered solutions are greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: How about not creating an infinite amount of buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You produce an endless loop in the `while(1 == 1 )`

This infinite loop is placed in a constructor, so that will never finish. When you created enough buttons, your program will finally go out of memory.